# Magento: How can I get at all the cart data from the form_key

Tags: php, magento

I have added a form onto the bottom of the cart page, and changed the cart page to redirect to my own custom page.

This custom page currently just outputs the submitted data from the previous page, like so: `print_r($_POST);`

This produces the following output:

```
Array
(
    [form_key] => 2AJOmd7GhFVICntG
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [20] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

So my question is, how can I get at all the cart data from the `form_key`.

A solution in pure PHP would be preferable. This is Magento 1.9.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to retrieve only magento cart data then use below mentioned code.

```
$itemsCollection = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();


$itemsVisible = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();


$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo 'ID: '.$item->getProductId().'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$item->getName().'<br />';
    echo 'Sku: '.$item->getSku().'<br />';
    echo 'Quantity: '.$item->getQty().'<br />';
    echo 'Price: '.$item->getPrice().'<br />';
    echo "<br />";          
}


$totalItems = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCount();
$totalQuantity = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsQty();

$subTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
$grandTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
```

Or if you want to get posted data from cart page form you have to use below mentioned code to get the submitted data.

```
$post = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();

print_r($post);
```